# How to republish sensor_msgs/FluidPressure as the geometry_msgs/PointStamped?

Tags: ros, sensors

m doing some underwater UUV Gazebo simulation and would like to use the

> ```
> hector_pose_estimation
> ```

package to fuse IMU and Fluid pressure sensors input for pose estimation. But when running the node I got ERROR

```
Client [/hector_pose_estimation] wants topic /rexrov2/pressure to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PointStamped/c63aecb41bfdfd6b7e1fac37c7cbe7bf], but our version has [sensor_msgs/FluidPressure/804dc5cea1c5306d6a2eb80b9833befe]. Dropping connection.
```

So my Pressure Sensor has `sensor_msgs/FluidPressure` but the package wants `pressure_height (geometry_msgs/PointStamped)` as input. Any help how to How to republish `sensor_msgs/FluidPressure` as the `geometry_msgs/PointStamped`?

Tnaks

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no node that does this direct translation. That being said, getting depth from a pressure is somewhat trivial. This can be done via the equation `P=ρgh`. Here:

> P = Pressure in Pascals
>
> ρ = Fluid density
>
> g = Acceleration due to gravity
>
> h = Depth

Roughly speaking the density for freshwater is 997.04 kg/m^3 and 1023.60 kg/m^3 for salt water. Acceleration, on Earth, is 9.8 m/s^2 and your pressure is coming off the ros topic. If you have a `sensor_msgs/FluidPressure` callback defined as `pressure_callback` it would look something like this

```
def pressure_callback(msg):
    pressure = msg. fluid_pressure
    depth = pressure / (997.04 * 9.8) #This assumes fresh water

    output_msg = PointMessage()
    output_msg.z = depth
    some_publisher.publish(output_msg)
```